# Help me understand how the conflict between immutability and running time is handled in Clojure

Tags: clojure, immutability, hashset, performance

Clojure truly piqued my interest, and I started going through a tutorial on it:
http://java.ociweb.com/mark/clojure/article.html

Consider these two lines mentioned under "Set":

```
(def stooges (hash-set "Moe" "Larry" "Curly")) ; not sorted
(def more-stooges (conj stooges "Shemp")) ; -> #{"Moe" "Larry" "Curly" "Shemp"}
```

My first thought was that the second operation should take constant time to complete; otherwise functional language might have little benefit over an object-oriented one. One can easily imagine a need to start with [nearly] empty set, and populate it and shrink it as we go along. So, instead of assigning the new result to more-stooges, we could re-assign it to itself.

Now, by the marvelous promise of functional languages, side effects are not to be concerned with. So, sets `stooges` and `more-stooges` should not work on top of each other ever. So, either the creation of `more-stooges` is a linear operation, or they share a common buffer (like Java's `StringBuffer`) which would seem like a very bad idea and conflict with immutability (subsequently `stooges` can drop an element one-by-one).

I am probably reinventing a wheel here. it seems like the `hash-set` would be more performant in `clojure` when you start with the maximum number of elements and then remove them one at a time until empty set as oppose to starting with an empty set and growing it one at a time.

The examples above might not seem terribly practical, or have workarounds, but the object-oriented language like Java/C#/Python/etc. has no problem with either growing or shrinking a set one or few elements at a time while also doing it fast.

A [functional] language which guarantees(or just promises?) immutability would not be able to grow a set as fast. Is there another idiom that one can use which somehow can help avoiding doing that?

For someone familiar with `Python`, I would mention set comprehension versus an equivalent loop approach. The running time of the two is tiny bit different, but that has to do with relative speeds of `C`, `Python`, interpreter and not rooted in complexity. The problem I see is that set comprehension is *often* a better approach, but **NOT ALWAYS** the best approach, for the readability might suffer a great deal.

Let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: http://dissociatedpress.net/2007/02/26/peak-vs-pique/

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey, you are a chess-playin, Capuchino-drinkin ilitist.

Comment: Awe shucks (blush) :-) Just looked up "ilitist". It doesn't mean someone who's illiterate and proud of it. "ileitis" is a bowel disease. I'm sure you didn't mean that either :)

Answer (score 8):

The core Immutable data structures are one of the most fascinating parts of the language for me also. their is a lot to answering this question and Rich does a really great job of it in this video:

http://blip.tv/file/707974

The core data structures:

- are actually fully immutable
- the old copies are also immutable
- performance does not degrade for the old copies
- access is constant (actually bounded <= a constant)
- all support efficient appending, concatenating (except lists and seqs) and chopping

How do they do this???

- the secret: it's **pretty much all trees** under the hood (actually a trie).

But what if i really want to edit somthing in place?

- you can use clojure's [transients](http://clojure.org/transients) to edit a structure in place and then produce a immutable version (in constant time) when you are ready to share it.

as a little background: a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is a tree where all the common elements of the key are hoisted up to the top of the tree. the sets and maps in clojure use trie where the indexes are a hash of the key you are looking for. it then breaks the hash up into small chunks and uses each chunk as the key to one level of the hash-trie. This allows the common parts of both the new and old maps to be shared and the access time is bounded because there can only be a fixed number of branches because the hash used as in input has a fixed size.

Using these hash tries also helps prevent big slowdowns during the re-balancing used by a lot of other persistent data structures. so you will actually get fairly constant wall-clock-access-time.

I really reccomend the (relativly short)_ book: [Purely Functional Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504)
In it he covers a lot of really interesting structures and concepts like "removing amortization" to allow true constant time access for queues. and things like lazy-persistent queues. the author even offers a free copy in [pdf here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.64.3080&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: Is a "trei" different to a trie or is it just a typo?

Comment: its trei (pronounced try) I just had a bit of keyboard trouble :)

Comment: From the wikipedia article: "The term trie comes from 'retrieval.' Following the etymology, the inventor, Edward Fredkin, pronounces it 'tree'. However, it is pronounced 'try' by other authors."

Answer (score 3):

Clojure's data structures are *persistent*, which means that they are immutable but use structural sharing to support efficient "modifications". See the section on [immutable data structures](http://clojure.org/functional_programming) in the Clojure docs for a more thorough explanation. In particular, it states

> Specifically, this means that the new version can't be created using a full copy, since that would require linear time. Inevitably, persistent collections are implemented using linked data structures, so that the new versions can share structure with the prior version.

[These](http://blog.higher-order.net/2009/02/01/understanding-clojures-persistentvector-implementation/) [posts](http://blog.higher-order.net/2009/09/08/understanding-clojures-persistenthashmap-deftwice/), as well as some of [Rich Hickey's talks](http://clojure.blip.tv/posts?view=archive&nsfw=dc), give a good overview of the implementation of persistent data structures.

Comment: How complicated are deletes? Suppose I have 10 different sets or dictionaries, where they are created incrementally. And then I delete a node that is common to all 10 from the very first set/dict (the one containing just one element). What will clojure do and how long will it take?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the set/dictionary is built incrementally or all at once. A delete is just as efficient as an add -- it's effectively a constant time operation.